# Connect to Neptune DB with SageMaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-neptune, graph-notebook

I was able to test out my connection successfully to my Neptune DB from within Neptune Notebooks and was able to perform bulk load and query with no issues but when trying to connect to SageMaker studio then I get connection error. I tried using the recommended way using gremlin-python library.

Is there anything else I need to do? Do I need to create a separate endpoint just for SageMaker? Do I need another set of permissions ?

Answer (score 1):

The [graph-notebook](https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook) project today supports Jupyter and Jupyter Labs. These can be self hosted or hosted on Amazon SageMaker. Currently SageMaker Studio is not supported as there is extra work needed to get the magics and widgets working in that environment.  This is an item that is on the graph-notebook todo list.

You should be able to use Gremlin Python from a regular SageMaker Studio notebook but you will need to follow the guidance for how to work when the event loop is already running. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71343541/can-i-use-the-gremlin-python-client-in-a-jupyter-notebook-and-avoid-event-loop-e) for more information on that

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already been using the syntax you pointed out in another question/post but I continue to get an error saying:
It cannot connect to host <endpoint-name>:<port> ssl:default [Connect call failed (ip-address, port)].

Is there a way to check if I am using the right host or endpoint (already using same on Neptune notebook for bulk load and other things and works fine), maybe a different variation?

I've also tried wss:// and ws:// based on things I've read. Do I need to add https also?

Comment: I would start by seeing if a simple `curl` to the `/status` endpoint of the Neptune cluster works from a terminal tab of the SageMaker Instance. Something like: `curl https://<neptune-endpoint>:8182/status`